# Virtualenv for bash

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I really like `virtualenv` when working with python code and am wondering if there existed some tool which could emulate some of it when working in `bash`.

What I want is some cleanly reverseble way of setting environment variables by loading/unloading configurations.

I know about a lot of tools which do some magic when entering some directory, but I guess I wouldn't want to start from something like that.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it's what you're looking for but I have this on [my rc files](https://github.com/git2samus/rcfiles):

```
mklab() {
    # creates small test environments for scripting
    local d=$(mktemp -d) && cd "$d" || return 1
    clear; bash --login --noprofile --norc
    cd - && rm -r "$d"
}; export -f mklab
```

it puts you in a temp directory with a clean shell to make tests and removes it afterwards.

virtualenv is a bad example for bash because here you don't "install" libraries, if you're looking for a way to easily switch between bash versions you should mention that on the question.

Comment: Oh yes, one does "install" "libraries": for example by sourcing sh files.

Comment: nah that's just running code, it would be the same if you copy-pasted the sourced file in your terminal. It's not a library and it's not an installation, at most it would be a set of function declarations that you manually load everytime you run the shell.

Answer (score 0):

A naive attempt:

to load env:

```
shvirtualenv() ( source "$1"; VIRTUALENV="$1" bash; )
```

On exit one should save variables (or not if undesirable):

```
shvirtualenv_exit() {
    # one could ask here whether to save the env:
    declare -x > $VIRTUALENV
}

trap EXIT shvirtualenv_exit
```

CONS:

- It does not handle inheritance well: if you want to source another env on save it will save all and further changes in parent env are not reflected.
- Another problem is with multiple sessions (just open another terminal) - now you will end up with conflicts

TODO:

- I would love to see separate history for the env.
- per-project bashrc

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old question, I see, and the answers here are similarly out of date...

I believe the current (2015) way of doing this with [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) is:

In ${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin/postactivate:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.local_settings
```

In ${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin/predeactivate:

```
unset DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
```

Oneliners:

```
echo 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=EOS.local_settings' >> ${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin/postactivate
echo 'unset DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' >> ${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin/predeactivate
```

---

I like [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which offers, amongst other things:

- `workon myvenv` # activate my virtualenv
- `setvirtualenvproject` # from the project directory, allows:
- `cdproject`
- `cdvirtualenv`
- `deactivate`

YMMV